# how to get a response of running an API on remote rails server from another rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have to rails application, my aim is to call an API on remote rails application and get back the result of that API.
for example:
1st Application has `update()` API which does some processing and create a hash called `data`
Now I want to call `update()` from 2nd Application and want `data` hash in response.

what I am doing right now is using `RestClient.get(url)` url is 1st application's url appended with API name.

Does this solve my requirement or is there any other better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question,
I can use `render :test => data.to_json` in my remote server API, this well parse and send `data` hash in response to the calling application, this solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

There's a product called `ActiveResource`... used to be built into rails but is now a separate gem.

https://github.com/rails/activeresource

We use it a lot at where I work.

Although it has a few quirks, it does a reasonably good job of providing  ActiveRecord-like behaviour.  You do `Model.save` and it sends a json to the back end app's `modelscontroller#create` or `modelscontroller#update` actions.

Comment: ActiveResource is a good option but only if you want to query only record, i want to call api which will query records locally and create a hash for me.
then I will fetch it, this will protect me from making so many queries to remote application.

Comment: You can do collections with ActiveResource.  It supports all the standard actions... show / edit / update / new / create / delete and also index for collectons (multiple records).  And you can use ActiveResource GET to retrieve a hash of whatever the API end creates... it can be a true hash, doesn't have to be model based.

Answer (score 1):

For that type of purpose I would use HTTParty, light weight HTTP ruby client.

Simply call

```
resp = HTTParty.get(url)
resp.body # => displays body of the response
JSON.parse(resp.body) # => parses JSON if you need to parse it
```

Reference:
https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty

Comment: your answer can be used at calling application side after i get response back :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on this kind of project, but I'm using AJAX to get data from another site. You have to take care of Cross Site Scripting, making the calls secure, and important of all, if your one site is running on `https`, then there may be problems if your other application is running on `http`.